# how can disable scroll recyclerView when moving map?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, vertical-scrolling, neshan-map

I created a recyclerView that has several items but the problem is when I want to look for the address inside the map
When I scroll through the map, the recycler view shifts and the map loses scrollability.

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A76L6.png)

//Recycler View Adapter Class

```
public class AddressAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressAdapter.Holder> {

    private List<FakeAddressList> objectList;

    public AddressAdapter(List<FakeAddressList> list) {
        this.objectList = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_address, parent, false);
        return new Holder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindAddressList(objectList.get(position));
        
        holder.imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                objectList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.imgEditLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AddAddressFragment addressFragment = new AddAddressFragment();

                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Title", objectList.get(position).getTitle());
                bundle.putString("Address", objectList.get(position).getAddress());
                bundle.putString("Phone", objectList.get(position).getPhoneNumber());
                addressFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                ft.replace(R.id.content_view, addressFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });

        holder.FooterLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                AddDataFragment addDataFragment = new AddDataFragment();

                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Title", objectList.get(position).getAddress());
                bundle.putString("Address", objectList.get(position).getAddress());
                bundle.putString("Phone", objectList.get(position).getPhoneNumber());
                addDataFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                ft.replace(R.id.content_view, addDataFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objectList.size();
    }


    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView txtTitle;
        public TextView txtSelect;
        public TextView txtAddress;
        public TextView txtPhone;
        public ImageView imgClose;
        public ImageView imgEditLocation;
        public ConstraintLayout FooterLayout;
        public MapView map;

        public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
            txtPhone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNumber);
            txtSelect = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSelect);
            imgClose = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
            imgEditLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgEditLocation);
            FooterLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FooterLayout);
            map = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);

            txtTitle.setTypeface(Font_shabnam);
            txtAddress.setTypeface(Font_shabnam);
            txtPhone.setTypeface(Font_shabnam);
            txtSelect.setTypeface(Font_shabnam);

        }


        public void bindAddressList(final FakeAddressList fakeAddressList) {
            txtTitle.setText(fakeAddressList.getTitle());
            txtAddress.setText(fakeAddressList.getAddress());
            txtPhone.setText(fakeAddressList.getPhoneNumber());


            if (fakeAddressList.getLng() != null) {
                double lng = Double.valueOf(fakeAddressList.getLng());
                double lat = Double.valueOf(fakeAddressList.getLat());

                addUserMarker(new LngLat(lng, lat));

                map.setFocalPointPosition(
                        new LngLat(Double.valueOf(fakeAddressList.getLng()), Double.valueOf(fakeAddressList.getLat())), 0.25f);

            } else {
                LngLat focalPoint;
                focalPoint = new LngLat(51.33800, 35.69997);
                map.setFocalPointPosition(focalPoint, 0f);
            }

            map.setZoom(15, 0.25f);
            map.getLayers().add(NeshanServices.createBaseMap(NeshanMapStyle.STANDARD_DAY));

        }

        // This method gets a LngLat as input and adds a marker on that position
        private void addUserMarker(LngLat loc) {
            Marker marker;
            VectorElementLayer userMarkerLayer;

            userMarkerLayer = NeshanServices.createVectorElementLayer();
            map.getLayers().add(userMarkerLayer);
            // Creating marker style. We should use an object of type MarkerStyleCreator, set all features on it
            // and then call buildStyle method on it. This method returns an object of type MarkerStyle
            MarkerStyleCreator markStCr = new MarkerStyleCreator();
            markStCr.setSize(20f);
//        markStCr.setBitmap(BitmapUtils.createBitmapFromAndroidBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_marker)));
            markStCr.setBitmap(BitmapUtils.createBitmapFromAndroidBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(itemView.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_cherry)));
            MarkerStyle markSt = markStCr.buildStyle();

            // Creating user marker
            marker = new Marker(loc, markSt);

            // Clearing userMarkerLayer
//            userMarkerLayer.clear();

            // Adding user marker to userMarkerLayer, or showing marker on map!
            userMarkerLayer.add(marker);
        }

    }

}
```

Recycler View Xml Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/HeaderLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/_orange_shape_b_r_l"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgClose"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgEditLocation"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_location"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="تهرانپارس"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgEditLocation"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgEditLocation"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgClose"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgClose" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/MiddleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/HeaderLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <org.neshan.ui.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAddress"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_address"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mapView"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="خیابان فلانی کوچه 1"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgAddress"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgAddress" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPhone"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgAddress"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0916123456"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgPhone"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgPhone" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/FooterLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/_black_shape_t_r_l"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/MiddleLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSelect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="انتخاب"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

//Fragment that Load Recyclerview

```
public class RegisterAddressFragment extends Fragment
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    private RecyclerView recycler_SelectAddress;
    private Button btnNewAddress;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ConstraintLayout MainLayout;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private ArrayList<FakeAddressList> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        this.bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            list.add(new FakeAddressList(bundle.getString("Title"),
                    bundle.getString("Address"),
                    bundle.getString("Phone"),
                    bundle.getString("Lng"),
                    bundle.getString("Lat")));
        }
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register_address, container, false);

        init(v);
        initRecyclerView();
        return v;
    }

    private void init(View v) {
        recycler_SelectAddress = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_SelectAddress);
        btnNewAddress = v.findViewById(R.id.btnNewAddress);

        btnNewAddress.setOnClickListener(this);


        progressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        MainLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Do some stuff
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        MainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });
            }
        };
        thread.start(); //start the thread
    }


    private void initRecyclerView() {

        list.add(new FakeAddressList("اصفهان", "شاهین شهر خیابان نوشین پلاک 1", "987654321"));
        list.add(new FakeAddressList("اهواز", "کیانپارس کوچه بنی هاشم پلاک 33", "123456789"));

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        AddressAdapter addressAdapter = new AddressAdapter(list);
        recycler_SelectAddress.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recycler_SelectAddress.setAdapter(addressAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnNewAddress:
                AddAddressFragment addressFragment = new AddAddressFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_view, addressFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                break;
        }

    }


}
```

Fragment Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/tusi"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/red2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
      tools:visibility="visible"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/recycler_SelectAddress"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnNewAddress"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnNewAddress"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:backgroundTint="@color/navy_blue"
          android:insetLeft="0dp"
          android:insetTop="0dp"
          android:insetRight="0dp"
          android:insetBottom="0dp"
          android:text="آدرس جدید"
          android:textSize="22sp"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :
I added below code in the adapter of the recyclerview

```
  map.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                     itemView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```